# make Restore-DfsrPreservedFiles continue after long path error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get Powershells `Restore-DfsrPreservedFiles` to restore about 100GB of files that got placed into the DfsrPrivate\PreExisting folder. I've got the Command all worked out and it does work until it hits a file that causes a path name too long error. At this point have 99.9GB restore with 1 file missing I can get from backups later is not a problem.

I can't figure out (if its possible) to make it skip the 1 or 2 files its having problems with and keep going.

Comment: powershell in itself is limited to 260 characters for path names and since the cmdlet doesnt itself offer an option to ignore errors i think you are stuck with that. There is also a thread on technet about this problem and the suggested solution was to either shorten the path or use .net as a workaround. Here is the link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/14fc8393-d616-408f-abad-49a3ccb15585/windows-server-2012-r2-running-restoredfsrpreservedfiles-getting-path-file-name-or-both-are-too?forum=winserverfiles

Comment: @paul Thanks, I've solved the problem anyway now using my backups does mean a load of re-permissioning but it should be sorted for users tomorrow morning...

Comment: no problem, now that i think of it using `-erroraction silentlycontinue` might have worked

Comment: @Paul I did try `-erroraction inquire` to find out what options it would give.